# C++ project created in Visual Studio 2013 on Winidows 7 not compatible with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is most annoying and incomprehensible. I tried to open an older project, that was none the less last worked with in Visual Studio Express 2013 on Windows 7. Now I had to get a new computer, and have Windows 8. On opening the `.sln` or `.vcxproj` files, Visual Studio just tells me in the solution explorer that

> "this project is not compatible with the current edition"

If I open the older `.vcproj` project file, Visual Studio terminates the migration, showing a dialog box stating that

> "the system can not find the file specified"

Although, it doesn't give any information whatsoever about what file it is actually talking about.

Did anybody else ever have a similar problem? Currently I don't know what to do, except for recreating the whole project structure from scratch, but this really shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: try to run Visual Studio  as Administrator.

Comment: Hmmm, that at least yields a lot more information. Still nothing I could make heads or tails of, though. The activity log shows a lot of unexpected exceptions when loading packages (note: The project is pure C++, no .net or any kind of NuGets). here's a link to the activitylog, in case that helps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0skm4q6rsj44gdi/ActivityLog.xml?dl=0

Comment: based on the activity log; especially last two records (277, 278); I can guess that the problem is originated from 'NuGetVSEventsPackage'; try the solution mentioned here: http://nuwanlanka.com/?p=85

Comment: I tried the fix, messed up the timing, banged my head on the table and re-installed VisualStudio. It works now... thanks for the help!